# Inserting into association table (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am writing my first ASP.NET MVC project, and very inexperienced in this subject so please bear with me.

I have to use an existing database for a new application I need to build. I have set this up as a datasource, and used the ADO.NET Entity Data Model to select the tables I need. I have one table that holds categories associated with a parent record, joined by a unique ID. This table doesn't appear in the designer but comes the Associations folder. How do I insert records into this table? Or am I going about this completely wrong?

Here is the code I have so far for Create:

```
//
// POST: /Home/Create
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "KeyID")] KeyDate dateToCreate, int topic, int level, int subject, int audience)
{
    dateToCreate.Created = DateTime.Now;
    dateToCreate.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    keyDateRepository.Add(dateToCreate);
    keyDateRepository.Save();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here's the code for the repository:

```
//
// Insert/Delete Methods

public void Add(KeyDate keyDate)
{
   db.KeyDates.AddObject(keyDate);
}

[...]

//
// Persistence

public void Save()
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to create the associated record at the same time as creating the KeyDate?

Comment: Hi Brian. Do you know how I'd go about doing that? When using the IntelliSense it tells me of the other entities, but not the associated one.

Comment: Hello, so I understand correctly, what you are saying is if I have a Users and Roles table, if it has an association table of UserRoles that links Users to Roles, how do you update that table?  In Entity Framework 4, these are directly available, but I believe hidden in V1... So you are using V1?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to do. It seems that I am using EF4, so still not sure why that table is not available. Maybe something else I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. I didn't realise that all I needed to do was to add the categories to the instance of that object.

```
dateToCreate.Categories.Add(keyDateRepository.GetCategory(topic));
dateToCreate.Categories.Add(keyDateRepository.GetCategory(level));
dateToCreate.Categories.Add(keyDateRepository.GetCategory(subject));
dateToCreate.Categories.Add(keyDateRepository.GetCategory(audience));
```